# Mediastream goes defunct

Tags: linux, kill, mono

I am running my donnet framework based application using mono in Linux Ubuntu. My application uses linphone's mediastream command to open the RTP socket and hook the audio device.
I am using the following mediastream command to call from my application:

```
mediastream (arguments......)
```

Every thing is working fine but when i am trying to kill the mediastream using the `killall` command, it goes defunct. I am giving the following command from my application:

```
killall mediastream
```

What I am doing wrong? How can I handle those defunct processes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linphone's mediastream require CTRL+C (SIGINT) to close properly and killall default signal is SIGTERM. So you can try SIGINT signal in killall command as follows:

```
killall -SIGINT mediastream
```

or

```
killall -2 mediastream
```